# How can I download image from img tag?

Tags: php, html, image

When I navigate to this site http://stars-fetcher.herokuapp.com/#20300909 inside chrome dev tools I am trying to extract src of img tag but after I open src in new tab weird text appears rather than png, jpeg etc. I don't know php and it's probably related with some php script.

Sample HTML Element:

```
<img style="margin-left:20px" src="https://stars.bilkent.edu.tr/srs/scripts/image.php?ID=20300909&amp;cry=a25c4f5c1bd773d480a5475917572668" height="500">
```

Answer (score 2):

Save the output to a file and change the extension to **.jpg**.